# C++ templates specializations and xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, templates, c++11, c++14

I have the following error from Xcode:

> Template argument for template template parameter must be a class template or type alias template

However the same exact code works fine in Visual Studio.

```
template< typename T_NODE, template< typename > class T_ALLOCATOR >
class qt_fixed_pool_general {};

template< template< typename, int > class T_ALLOCATOR, int T_COUNT >
struct static_to_dynamic
{ template< typename T_NODE > using t_allocator = T_ALLOCATOR< T_NODE,T_COUNT >; };

template< typename T_NODE, int T_COUNT >
struct safe_array {};

template< class T_NODE, int T_COUNT >
class qt_fixed_pool_static : public qt_fixed_pool_general< 
      T_NODE, 
      static_to_dynamic< safe_array, T_COUNT >::t_allocator >
{};
```

Any ideas what may be going on?
I am using Xcode 7.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that when parsing (not instantiating) the template, the compiler cannot know that `t_allocator` will be a template and not, say, a static data member. You have to tell it:

```
template< class T_NODE, int T_COUNT >
class qt_fixed_pool_static : public qt_fixed_pool_general< 
      T_NODE, 
      static_to_dynamic< safe_array, T_COUNT >::template t_allocator >
{};                                           //^^^^^^^^
```

[[Live example]](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b18e444dfe42c852)

Note the `template` keyword added between `::` and `t_allocator`.

The reason why this works in Visual Studio is that VS is not standard-compliant in its template parsing (and has never been): it doesn't do two-phase lookup properly, but instead postpones all name resolution until instantiation time, so it does not trip on errors like this.

Comment: @Nickreal03 The SO way to say thanks is to [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) the answer which solved your problem (at most one accepted answer per question). This marks the question as solved and gives both you and the answerer some reputation.

Comment: Accepted! Thanks again, I did not know that neither.